# pcl::MarchingCubesRBF doesn't output mesh

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, geometry-surface, 3d-reconstruction, marching-cubes

I need to use Marching Cubes based on Radial Basis Function so I looked up this algorithm implemented in PCL. 
Actually I'm using PCL v1.6 so the function is:

```
    pcl::MarchingCubesRBF
```

The problem is that it doesn't work, that is it doesn't create any triangles: sometimes the output is '0 triangles created', at times running blocks my machine.
Anyway my implementation is:

```
    pcl::MarchingCubesRBF<pcl::PointNormal> mc;
    pcl::PolygonMesh::Ptr triangles(new pcl::PolygonMesh);
    mc.setInputCloud (cloud_with_normals);
    mc.setSearchMethod (tree);
    mc.reconstruct (*triangles);
```

I tried with different files like input but neither of them works. One of it is https://github.com/FabiApfelkern/cloudfinish/blob/master/cat.pcd

I found there was a bug about the implementation in pcl: http://dev.pointclouds.org/issues/768
However I don't understand if it is solved in pcl v1.6. Let me know how could I solve if it is possible.

I'm using C++ with VS2010

Comment: Does no one knows news about this algorithm?

Comment: I worked to improve the code, adding the followings: `mc.setGridResolution(1,1,1);
      mc.setIsoLevel(0.5); //between 0 and 1
      mc.setPercentageExtendGrid(5);` Running this code with this settings I get a **Debug Assertion Failed** by VS2010, that is: _vector subscript out of range_ . Could someone provide any suggestion?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I tried it Marching Cubes on v1.7 and the error persists.

Comment: Maybe [this issue](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/issues/3961) I created has some relevance for you too

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it setting the grid resolution:

```cpp
mc.setGridResolution (100, 100, 100);
mc.reconstruct (*triangles);
```

The grid resolution is the amount of voxels used in x, y and z directions. So if you set it to `1, 1, 1`, there will be only one voxel - and thus not a very good representation of your point cloud. The higher the resolution, the more expensive it will be, but it also improves the quality of the resulting mesh.